# Cannot black out previous dates in my calendar - PHP

Tags: php

I am using a calendar in which i am having trouble making the previous dates unavailable. At the moment my calendar ha links for each date and when you click a date it shows the value on another page. However i need all make all the dates that have already passed unavailable. I know it is something to do with the if statement near the end of the code but i can't figure it out. Here is my code

```
<?php
$monthNames = Array("January", "February", "March", "April", "May", "June", "July", 
"August", "September", "October", "November", "December");
?>
<?php
$cMonth = isset($_REQUEST["month"]) ? $_REQUEST["month"] : date("n");
$cYear = isset($_REQUEST["year"]) ? $_REQUEST["year"] : date("Y");

$prev_year = $cYear;
$next_year = $cYear;
$prev_month = $cMonth-1;
$next_month = $cMonth+1;

if ($prev_month == 0 ) {
    $prev_month = 12;
    $prev_year = $cYear - 1;
}
if ($next_month == 13 ) {
    $next_month = 1;
    $next_year = $cYear + 1;
}
?><!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Hook Up</title>
</head>
<style type="text/css">
        table {
        border: 1px solid black;
        border-collapse: collapse;
    }
    th {
        border: 1px solid black;
        padding: 6px;
        font-weight: bold;
        background: #ccc;
    }
    td {
        border: 1px solid black;
        padding: 6px;
        vertical-align: top;
        width: 100px;
        }
</style>
<script type="text/javascript">
function eventWindow(url) {
        event_popupWin = window.open(url, 'event',
        'resizable=yes, scrollbars=yes, toolbar=no, width=400, height=400);
        event_popupWin.opener = self;
}
</script>
<body>
<h1>Select a Night Out</h1>
<table width="200">
<tr align="center">
<td bgcolor="#999999" style="color:#FFFFFF">
<table width="100%" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
<tr>
<td width="50%" align="left">  <a href="<?php echo $_SERVER["PHP_SELF"] . "?month=".                     $prev_month . "&year=" . $prev_year; ?>" style="color:#FFFFFF">Previous</a></td>
<td width="50%" align="right"><a href="<?php echo $_SERVER["PHP_SELF"] . "?month=".  $next_month . "&year=" . $next_year; ?>" style="color:#FFFFFF">Next</a>  </td>
</tr>
</table>
</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td align="center">
<table width="100%" border="0" cellpadding="2" cellspacing="2">
<tr align="center">
<td colspan="7" bgcolor="#999999" style="color:#FFFFFF"><strong><?php echo    $monthNames[$cMonth-1].' '.$cYear; ?></strong></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td align="center" bgcolor="#999999" style="color:#FFFFFF"><strong>S</strong></td>
<td align="center" bgcolor="#999999" style="color:#FFFFFF"><strong>M</strong></td>
<td align="center" bgcolor="#999999" style="color:#FFFFFF"><strong>T</strong></td>
<td align="center" bgcolor="#999999" style="color:#FFFFFF"><strong>W</strong></td>
<td align="center" bgcolor="#999999" style="color:#FFFFFF"><strong>T</strong></td>
<td align="center" bgcolor="#999999" style="color:#FFFFFF"><strong>F</strong></td>
<td align="center" bgcolor="#999999" style="color:#FFFFFF"><strong>S</strong></td>
</tr>
<?php 
$timestamp = mktime(0,0,0,$cMonth,1,$cYear);
$maxday = date("t",$timestamp);
$thismonth = getdate ($timestamp);
$startday = $thismonth['wday'];
$today = date('j');
$currentmonth = date('n');
for ($i=0; $i<($maxday+$startday); $i++) {
if(($i % 7) == 0 ){
echo "<tr>";
}
if($i < $startday){
echo ("<td class='cell cell_txt'> </td>");
} else {
if (($i - $startday + 1) == $today && $currentmonth == $cMonth){
echo ("<td class='cell_today cell_txt'>".($i-$startday+ 1)."</td>");
} else {
echo ("<td class='cell cell_txt'><a href=\"hook.php?day=".($i - $startday +   1)."&amp;month=".$cMonth."&amp;year=".$cYear."\">".($i - $startday + 1)."</a></td>");
}
}
if(($i % 7) == 6 ) {
echo "</tr>\n";
}
}
?>
</table>
</td>
</tr>
</table>
</body>
    </html>
```

If anyone can help it would be greatly appreciated. Cheers

Answer (score 0):

if you add following line

```
$cDay = isset($_REQUEST["day"]) ? $_REQUEST["day"] : date("d");
```

below this line

```
$cYear = isset($_REQUEST["year"]) ? $_REQUEST["year"] : date("Y");
```

and change this line

```
if (($i - $startday + 1) == $today && $currentmonth == $cMonth){
```

to:

```
if ((($i - $startday + 1) == $today && $currentmonth == $cMonth) OR ( (($i - $startday + 1) == $cDay) && ($currentmonth == $cMonth))  ){
```

That will black out the date that is passed in.

If you want to pass in multiple dates, i.e. pick one date 2013-01-18, the page reloads and blanks out the 18th then want to pick a second date e.g. 2013-01-22 and have the page reload and blank out both the 18th and the 22nd then you will need to change the inputs to arrays and add the previous selected dates into hidden fields to be resubmitted.

If you just want to black out one date then the code changes will work.

Hope this helps.

**Update to black out all previous date to the selected:**

```
<?php
    $monthNames = Array("January", "February", "March", "April", "May", "June", "July",
        "August", "September", "October", "November", "December");
    ?>
    <?php
    $sMonth = isset($_REQUEST["smonth"]) ? $_REQUEST["smonth"] : date("n");
    $sYear = isset($_REQUEST["syear"]) ? $_REQUEST["syear"] : date("Y");
    $cMonth = isset($_REQUEST["month"]) ? $_REQUEST["month"] : '';
    $cYear = isset($_REQUEST["year"]) ? $_REQUEST["year"] : '';
    $cDay = isset($_REQUEST["day"]) ? $_REQUEST["day"] : '';

    //echo __line__." Dates in ".$cDay." ".$cMonth.", ".$cYear."<br>";

    $prev_year = $sYear;
    $next_year = $sYear;
    $prev_month = $sMonth - 1;
    $next_month = $sMonth + 1;

    if ($prev_month == 0) {
        $prev_month = 12;
        $prev_year = $sYear - 1;
    }
    if ($next_month == 13) {
        $next_month = 1;
        $next_year = $sYear + 1;
    }
    $nextPrevString = "&amp;month=$cMonth&amp;year=$cYear&amp;day=$cDay";
    $selectString = "&amp;smonth=$sMonth&amp;syear=$sYear";
    ?><!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
        <head>
            <title>Hook Up</title>
        </head>
        <style type="text/css">
            table {
                border: 1px solid black;
                border-collapse: collapse;
            }
            th {
                border: 1px solid black;
                padding: 6px;
                font-weight: bold;
                background: #ccc;
            }
            td {
                border: 1px solid black;
                padding: 6px;
                vertical-align: top;
                width: 100px;
            }
        </style>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            function eventWindow(url) {
                event_popupWin = window.open(url, 'event', resizable=yes, scrollbars=yes, toolbar=no, width=400, height=400);
                event_popupWin.opener = self;
            }
        </script>
        <body>
            <h1>Select a Night Out</h1>
            <table width="200">
                <tr align="center">
                    <td bgcolor="#999999" style="color:#FFFFFF">
                        <table width="100%" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
                            <tr>
                                <td width="50%" align="left">  <a href="<?php echo $_SERVER["PHP_SELF"] . "?smonth=" . $prev_month . "&syear=" . $prev_year . $nextPrevString; ?>" style="color:#FFFFFF">Previous</a></td>
                                <td width="50%" align="right"><a href="<?php echo $_SERVER["PHP_SELF"] . "?smonth=" . $next_month . "&syear=" . $next_year . $nextPrevString; ?>" style="color:#FFFFFF">Next</a>  </td>
                            </tr>
                        </table>
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td align="center">
                        <table width="100%" border="0" cellpadding="2" cellspacing="2">
                            <tr align="center">
                                <td colspan="7" bgcolor="#999999" style="color:#FFFFFF"><strong><?php echo $monthNames[$sMonth - 1] . ' ' . $sYear; ?></strong></td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <td align="center" bgcolor="#999999" style="color:#FFFFFF"><strong>S</strong></td>
                                <td align="center" bgcolor="#999999" style="color:#FFFFFF"><strong>M</strong></td>
                                <td align="center" bgcolor="#999999" style="color:#FFFFFF"><strong>T</strong></td>
                                <td align="center" bgcolor="#999999" style="color:#FFFFFF"><strong>W</strong></td>
                                <td align="center" bgcolor="#999999" style="color:#FFFFFF"><strong>T</strong></td>
                                <td align="center" bgcolor="#999999" style="color:#FFFFFF"><strong>F</strong></td>
                                <td align="center" bgcolor="#999999" style="color:#FFFFFF"><strong>S</strong></td>
                            </tr>
                            <?php
                            $timestamp = mktime(0, 0, 0, $sMonth, 1, $sYear);
                            if ($cDay != '') {
                                $selectedDate = mktime(0, 0, 0, $cMonth, $cDay, $cYear);
                            } else {
                                $selectedDate = 0;
                            }
                            $maxday = date("t", $timestamp);
                            $thismonth = getdate($timestamp);
                            $startday = $thismonth['wday'];
                            $today = date('j');
                            $currentmonth = date('n');

                            for ($i = 0; $i < ($maxday + $startday); $i++) {
                                if (($i % 7) == 0) {
                                    echo "<tr>";
                                }
                                if ($i < $startday) {
                                    echo ("<td class='cell cell_txt'> </td>");
                                } else {
                                    $testDate = mktime(0, 0, 0, $sMonth, $i - $startday + 1, $sYear);
                                    if ($testDate < $selectedDate) {
                                        echo ("<td class='cell_today cell_txt'>" . ($i - $startday + 1) . "</td>");
                                    } else {
                                        echo ("<td class='cell cell_txt'><a href=\"" . $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'] . "?day=" . ($i - $startday + 1) . "&amp;month=" . $sMonth . "&amp;year=" . $sYear . $selectString . "\">" . ($i - $startday + 1) . "</a></td>");
                                    }
                                }
                                if (($i % 7) == 6) {
                                    echo "</tr>\n";
                                }
                            }
                            ?>
                        </table>
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </table>
        </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: Hi Tim, thanks for the help but this dosn't seem to have done anything. At the moment what I have is a calendar with a link to each day of each month so when you click a date it brings that value to the next page. However what i am looking for is to be able to choose any date in the future including todays date, but not to be able to choose any previous dates. (So no dates in the past can be chosen). Any help would be very useful

Comment: Hi Tom, sorry I though you only wanted to black out a single date not all dates before the the selected date.  I have added a new selection on the bottom of the answer to get you what you want.

Comment: Hi Tim, thanks for the help and sorry for annoying you. Its just with this code for the current date and month is working fine so todays date January 28th 2013 is working correctly all the previous dates are blacked out but when i go forward a month to February all the days are blacked out up to the 28th. The same when i go back a month to December all the days are blacked out up to the 28th, so the 28th, 29th , 30th, 31st are available. What im looking to do is for all the dates in the previous months to be unavailable and all the days in the future to be available. Thanks again for your help

Comment: Hi Tom, Sorry about that I have reworked the code to make all the blacked out dates problem go away.  I have had to make quite a few changes so I have posted the whole code.  Hope this is what you are after. :)

Comment: I am so sorry now Tim for being such a pain but this seems to have all the days available and when you click a day all the previous days are unavailable. What I am looking to do is have all the days before today unavailable, and all days after and including today available. So when you click one of these days the values show up on the hook.php page. I am so sorry for being such a pest

Comment: Hi Tom, I'm getting really confused about what you want now as the comment above lists things that are not in the question. but heres another shot add this above the for statement `$currentDateTest = mktime(0, 0, 0, date('n'), date('d'), date('Y'));` and change the if statement to `if (($testDate < $selectedDate) OR ($testDate <= $currentDateTest)) {`.  if you don't want the page to link back on itself then change the $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'] in the a to the page link you want.  If this isn't what you want please can you restate your question with all the points the code needs to do. Thanks Tim

Answer (score 0):

```html
<!-----use it will surely work -----!>

<?php
                        $monthNames = Array("January", "February", "March", "April", "May", "June", "July",
                            "August", "September", "October", "November", "December");
                        ?>

                        <?php
                        if (!isset($_REQUEST["day"])) $_REQUEST["day"] = date("d");
                        if (!isset($_REQUEST["month"])) $_REQUEST["month"] = date("n");
                        if (!isset($_REQUEST["year"])) $_REQUEST["year"] = date("Y");
                        ?>

                        <?php
                        $cDay = $_REQUEST["day"];
                        $cMonth = $_REQUEST["month"];
                        $cYear = $_REQUEST["year"];

                        $prev_year = $cYear;
                        $next_year = $cYear;
                        $prev_month = $cMonth - 1;
                        $next_month = $cMonth + 1;

                        if ($prev_month == 0) {
                            $prev_month = 12;
                            $prev_year = $cYear - 1;
                        }
                        if ($next_month == 13) {
                            $next_month = 1;
                            $next_year = $cYear + 1;
                        }
                        ?>
                        <div id="calendar_div" name="calendar_div">
                            <div class="table-responsive">
                                <table width="93%" style="border: none">
                                    <tr>
                                        <td>&nbsp;&nbsp;<a
                                                href="<?php echo $_SERVER["PHP_SELF"] . "?month=" . $prev_month . "&year=" . $prev_year; ?>"
                                                style="color:#FFFFFF"> < </a>
                                            <a href="<?php echo $_SERVER["PHP_SELF"] . "?month=" . $next_month . "&year=" . $next_year; ?>"
                                               style="color:#FFFFFF"> > </a></td>
                                        <td style="float: right">
                                            <h3 style="color: #ffffff;">  <?php echo $monthNames[$cMonth - 1] . ' ' . $cYear; ?></strong></h3>
                                        </td>
                                    </tr>
                                </table>

                                <table  class="table">

                                    <tr>
                                        <td style="color:#FFFFFF;border: none"><strong>Sun</strong></td>
                                        <td style="color:#FFFFFF;border: none"><strong>Mon</strong></td>
                                        <td style="color:#FFFFFF;border: none"><strong>Tue</strong></td>
                                        <td style="color:#FFFFFF;border: none"><strong>Wed</strong></td>
                                        <td style="color:#FFFFFF;border: none"><strong>Thr</strong></td>
                                        <td style="color:#FFFFFF;border: none"><strong>Fri</strong></td>
                                        <td style="color:#FFFFFF;border: none"><strong>Sat</strong></td>
                                    </tr>

                                    <?php

                                    $timestamp = mktime(0, 0, 0, $cMonth, 1, $cYear);
                                    $maxday = date("t", $timestamp);
                                    $thismonth = getdate($timestamp);
                                    $currentmonth = date('n');

                                    $startday = $thismonth['wday'];

                                    for ($i = 0; $i < ($maxday + $startday); $i++) {
                                        if (($i % 7) == 0) echo "<tr>\n";
                                        if ($i < $startday) echo "<td style='border: none'></td>\n";
                                        elseif(($i - $startday + 1) == $cDay && $currentmonth == $cMonth ){



                                            echo "<td  style='background-color: #cccccc'>". ($i - $startday + 1) ."</td>";}

                                        else{

                                            echo "<td  style='color: #ffffff; border: none'>". ($i - $startday + 1) ."</td></a>";}

                                        if(($i % 7) == 6 ) echo "</tr>";

                                    }

                                    ?>


                                </table>
```